# Error code: 1066. Not unique table/alias issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join three tables:

```
SELECT Songs.SongId,
Artist.ArtistFName,
Artist.ArtistLName,
Album.AlbumName,
Genre.GenreName, 
Songs.SongTrackNr,
Songs.SongName, 
Songs.SongDuration 

FROM
(((Album
INNER JOIN Songs ON Album.AlbumId = Songs.AlbumId)
INNER JOIN Ablum ON Album.ArtistId = Artist.ArtistId)
INNER JOIN Album ON Album.GenreId = Genre.GenreId);
```

But I am getting the not unique error, where should i put aliases on the Album table?

Thanks

Comment: Use table aliases, e.g. `Ablum a1 ON a1...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query,

```
SELECT Songs.SongId,
Artist.ArtistFName,
Artist.ArtistLName,
Album.AlbumName,
Genre.GenreName, 
Songs.SongTrackNr,
Songs.SongName, 
Songs.SongDuration 
FROM
Album Album
INNER JOIN Songs Songs 
ON (Album.AlbumId = Songs.AlbumId)
INNER JOIN Artist Artist
ON (Album.ArtistId = Artist.ArtistId)
INNER JOIN Genre Genre
ON (Album.GenreId = Genre.GenreId);
```

Comment: That worked out, but I wonder about the double statements, for example, Album Album, does the second one work as an alias?

Answer (score 2):

You have `Ablum` and `Album` in the `FROM` clause.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT s.SongId, ar.ArtistFName, ar.ArtistLName, a.AlbumName, g.GenreName, 
       s.SongTrackNr, s.SongName, s.SongDuration 
FROM Album INNER JOIN
     Songs s
     ON a.AlbumId = s.AlbumId INNER JOIN
     Artists ar
     ON a.ArtistId = ar.ArtistId INNER JOIN
     Genre g
     ON a.GenreId = g.GenreId;
```

The fix is to the table names.  In addition, notice the table aliases -- they make the query easier to write and to read.  Plus the parentheses are not needed in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: thanks, there was a small typo on Artists, it should be Artist, but now I am getting an error on a.AlbumName as error:1054 unknown column

Comment: And I have double checked and copy and pasted the proper column name

Comment: @user2371684 . . . Although you can choose to accept any answer you like, it is rather curious that you accepted essentially the same answer posted over half an hour later.